# Sharepoint 2010 : Hiding Edit in datsheet option from document library only

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am migrating MOSS 2007 site to sharepoint 2010 without UI upgrade. I noticed that document library action tab includes menu called "Edit in datasheet". I need to know how do I hide it from ONLY document library. Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution. Document Library settings->advance settings-> Allow items in this document library to be edited using the datasheet? = N

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to edit the Display form for the library DispForm.aspx using Sharepoint Designer and use some client side code (Javascript/Jquery) to hide the button.

If you have access to jquery something like this will do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("[text='Edit in Datasheet']").remove();
});
```

Check this [article](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=99) for more details

Comment: Thanks Luis for help. But I found another solution. Document Library settings->advance settings-> Allow items in this document library to be edited using the datasheet? = No